# Error in Java SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm using putty to write a Java program that takes in SQL, but I'm getting this error:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Chinook

I'm not sure what's going wrong.
Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Q1{
        public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
                Connection conn=null;
                String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Chinook";
                System.setProperty(driver,"");
                try{
                        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username","password");
                        System.out.println("Connected to the DB");
                        }
                        catch (SQLException ex){
                                System.out.println("SQLException:"+ ex.getMessage());
                        }
                }
}
```

Comment: Is running MySQL Server in your computer?

Answer (score 0):

This line is pretty much self explanatory
`: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Chinook`

You need to download a .jar file for jdbc i.e. jdbc.jar from [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html) and then add it to your claspath ( project )

Also another thing is that you have jdbc driver but it could be the case that you are trying to access mysql withouth appropriate db for that type of database